# Convert image to binary?

Tags: c#

I have an image (in .png format), and I want this picture to convert to binary.

How can this be done using C#?

Comment: What do you mean 'convert to binary'? Do you mean, for example, black and white?

Comment: Could you explain it a little more? An image already is binary. Do you want it decompressed, our do you want to access the pixels?

Comment: I have to write the binary data of the image to the screen using Response.BinaryWrite();

Comment: png is a binary format is there a different format you are thinking of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have a file use:-

```
 Response.ContentType = "image/png";
 Response.WriteFile(physicalPathOfPngFile);
```

Comment: How to convert it back to image?

Answer (score 26):

```
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
```

[File.ReadAllBytes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)

> Opens a binary file, reads the
>   contents of the file into a byte
>   array, and then closes the file.

Comment: Unless there is some need to process that array before sending it to the response you may as well let ASP.NET handle it using WriteFile

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
Byte[] result 
    = (Byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(yourImage, typeof(Byte[]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    BinaryReader streamreader = new BinaryReader(stream);

    byte[] data = streamreader.ReadBytes(stream.Length);
```

data would then contain the contents of the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the image into a byte array using [ImageConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter.aspx) class. Then specify the [mime type](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/) of your png image, and voila!

Here's an example:

```
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Byte[]));
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])tc.ConvertTo(img,tc));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("filename");
byte[] buffer;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

buffer = stream.ToArray(); // converted to byte array
stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] ImageToBinary(string imagePath)
    {
        FileStream fS = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] b = new byte[fS.Length];
        fS.Read(b, 0, (int)fS.Length);
        fS.Close();
        return b;
    }
```

just use above code i think your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;

FileStream fs=new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //Path is image location 
Byte[] bindata= new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)];
fs.Read(bindata, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
```