# Store images in database as binary data

Tags: c#, database, image, data-storage

What's the best way to store an image in a database in binary format, and how can I implement it using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer to converting your image to binary here:

[Convert image to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373032/c-howto-convert-image-to-binary)

You would need a BLOB column in your SQL database in order to be able to insert it.

**EDIT:**

If you want to retrieve it back from the database, you can use the following article to do so:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326502

Comment: why image column will not use for that?

Comment: I suggested a way to store it in binary format, as you asked. I have no experience with the Image column type, I store it in this BLOB - binary format, or as a Base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use the Image column type.

Comment: `image` is deprected (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). `varbinary(max)` is to be prefered for new development work.

Comment: what this BLOB column actually meant

Comment: IS it meant the binary to used ... i use image column. what it differ

Comment: varbinary or binary whats the difference??

Comment: Binary is fixed length, whereas Varbinary is variable length. This article explains it quite nicely: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx